# Select string using Expression Yii2 is detected as column

Tags: yii2, expression

I have a query like this :

```
use yii\db\Expression;

public function search($params)
{
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select([
                "ir.id",
                "ir.no_surat",
                "tc.level",
                "nominal" => 'tc.cleaning',
                new Expression("clean as tagihan"),
                "tc.ditagihkan_bulan"
            ])

        ->from('ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate as re')
        ->leftJoin(['ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report as ir'],
            "ir.id = re.inspection_id")
        ->innerJoin(['ydepotras_finance.tagihan_cleaning as tc'],
            " re.id = tc.repair_estimate_id");
}
```

Please see in `new Expression("clean as tagihan"),`
Yii2 detected`clean` as column. But I need the clean as value on tagihan's column

```
+----+-------------+
| id |   tagihan   |
+----+-------------+
| 1  |   clean     |
| 2  |   clean     |
+----+-------------+
```

**Update**

UNION in Yii2

```
$cleanigQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select([
            "ir.id",
            "ir.no_surat",
            "tc.level",
            "nominal" => 'tc.cleaning',
            new Expression("clean as tagihan"),
            "tc.ditagihkan_bulan"
        ])
        ->from('ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate as re')
        ->leftJoin(['ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report as ir'],
            "ir.id = re.inspection_id")
        ->innerJoin(['ydepotras_finance.tagihan_cleaning as tc'],
            " re.id = tc.repair_estimate_id");

$oneBarQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select([
            "ir.id",
            "ir.no_surat",
            "tob.level",
            "nominal" => 'tob.one_bar',
                new Expression("one_bar as tagihan"),
            "tob.ditagihkan_bulan"
        ])
        ->from('ydepotras_estimator.repair_estimate as re')
        ->leftJoin(['ydepotras_estimator.inspection_report as ir'],
            "ir.id = re.inspection_id")
        ->innerJoin(['ydepotras_finance.tagihan_one_bar as tob'],
            " re.id = tob.repair_estimate_id");
```

So, I can do something like this :

```
$cleanigQuery->union($oneBarQuery, true);

    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from(['u' => $cleanigQuery])
        ->orderBy('no_surat');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,

    ]);
```

Comment: Your code is fine, you only have tu put your striung to show into extra semicolons to tell sql that this is a string and no keyword or column like this:  `new Expression("'one_bar' as tagihan")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case you could use a literal select statement

```
          ->select("ir.id, ir.no_surat, tc.level, 
                tc.cleaning, 'clean' as tagihan, tc.ditagihkan_bulan")
```

Comment: I have try this way a lot of time, but still, Unknown column 'clean' in 'field list'

Comment: be sure you have a clean column and if it is could be you must assign the table alias .. answer  update

Comment: I am pretty sure, I dont have a column with 'clean' name

Comment: then if you don't have a column with name clean  .. why you are trying to select it ??' .. or better what do you mean with  "clean as tagihan" ?

Comment: I need this beacuse I need to using union. Please see my update

Comment: You mean that you need  a dummy column for obtain the same number (and type) of column  of a union expression?

Comment: In this case you need  a  literal value eg: 'clean' as tagihan  .. answer  updated .

Answer (score 4):

Like this: `$query->select("*,CONCAT('clean') as tagihan")`